# Use JS variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get geo location from web app , and this value i need to verify it and place selected="selected" in a dropdown menu, but i don't know how to get the JS variable and use it into PHP . Please Help me !

Get location:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);

 function foundLocation(position)
 {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var long = position.coords.longitude;
   alert('Found location: ' + lat + ', ' + long);
 }
 function noLocation()
 {
   alert('Could not find location');
 }
</script>
```

And i will have a select like this:

```
<select name="destination" id="start">
                                    <option value="Domiciliu">Domiciliu</option>
                                    <option value="Sediul 1" <?php if(lat >= 45.795517 && long <= 24.137433){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>Sediul 1</option>
                                    <option value="Sediul 2" <?php if(lat && long){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>Sediul 2</option>
                                    <option value="Vama" <?php if(lat && long){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>Vama</option>
                                    <option value="Hotel Hilton" <?php if(lat && long){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>Hotel Hilton</option>
                                    <option value="Hotel Golden Tulip" <?php if(lat && long){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>Hotel Golden Tulip</option>
                                    <option value="TESS" <?php if(lat && long){ echo"selected=\"selected\"";}else{} ?>>TESS</option>
                                    <option value="Alta locatie">Alta locatie</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: You need to send the value via an AJAX call to a php script, which returns a result to your JavaScript frontend

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use additional javascript to set the selectbox's value, like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById('start');
element.value = 'location_code_in_selectbox';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to store the data in `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables, and then submit those to the php on another page where you pull the variables into your script.

Answer (score -1):

In order to send the values to the server-side php script, you can either use an ajax request or an (invisible) form field that sends data on form submit.

You should read up about the request/response HTTP stuff and the distinction between client side and server side execution.

Anyways, if you don't strictly need to process the information on server side (php) it should be sufficient to mark the selected option directly with javascript/jquery:

```
if (/* long lat conditions*/) {
  $('#start').val('Sediul 1'); // mark Sediul 1 as selected
}
```